# how to use a custom core php library in symfony?

Tags: symfony

I am trying to add the payment gateway in symfony2.I cant get the right methods. how to call it in auto-load and controller. what is the structure to implement the custom library in symfony2.

Comment: @Put12co22mer2, sorry, missed first comment, deleting mine.

Comment: is your project base on the fullstack framework or are you using only some of the components ?

Comment: i just want to add the library of payment which is in core php. I dont know how to use it in controller and where to place the lib in folder?

Comment: require 'some_library.php'; http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php

Answer (score 0):

You can declare it as a service in app/services.yml

```
my_service:
    class: path/to/TestClass
    arguments: [@argument1, @argument2]
```

And in your controller call it through container:

```
/** @var TestClass $myService */
$myService = $this->get('my_service');
```

Comment: where to add the core php library in symfony2 ?

Comment: You can add it to a folder inside your bundle: lib or helper etc.

Answer (score 0):

Symfony standard edition bootstrap a ClassLoader.

You can define path to core php libraries by adding it to your `$loader`object in `project_root/web/app(_dev).php`

see http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/class_loader/class_loader.html

```
<?php

$loader = require_once __DIR__.'/../app/bootstrap.php.cache';

// PSR-0
$loader->addPrefix('ACME', __DIR__.'/vendor/acme/ACME/lib');

...
```

or change your `composer.json`

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
        /* ... */
        "ACME\\Util": "../your_path/ACME/lib/Util"
    }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

If the requested library is available on [packagist](https://packagist.org), install it using composer :

```
composer require <vendor>/<package-name>
```

The previous command assumes you have [composer](https://getcomposer.org) installed globally.

Otherwise, manually add your library in your project (in `src` or `lib` directory).
Then,  add it to your composer.json like :

```
// ...
"autoload": {
    // ...
    "psr-0": {
        // ...
        "Your\\Library": "lib/"
    }
},
```